# Injecting externalized value from properties file by annotation into Spring

Tags: spring

This method doesn't work 
How can I read my properties file and inject my variable in my Scheduled like:
@Scheduled(fixedRateString ="${frequence.move}")

---

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource( "resources.properties")

public class Scheduler {

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
        Scheduler.class);

@Autowired
public Environment envi;

public  static final String  time=applicationContext.getBean(Environment.class).getProperty("frequence.move";


@Scheduled(fixedRateString ="${frequence.move}")
      public void doTask() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext
                = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BatchConfigEMS.class);


    JobLauncher launcher = (JobLauncher) applicationContext.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job = (Job) applicationContext.getBean(Job.class);
    try {
        test();
        launcher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JobRestartException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please tell me you aren't using this code for real? Never load an application context to get beans... The fact that you do that basically renders everything useless. Also your solution will let you run into issues with performance, memory, weird transactional issues etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flawed in a couple of ways. Basically as soon as you feel the need to create an instance of an `ApplicationContext` you should stop, think and act. As generally that is a sign you are doing things wrong.

To get beans use auto wiring, wire the beans into the classes as they need.

First make your `Scheduler` a `@Component` instead of a `@Configuration` and auto wire the needed beans.

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

  @Autowired
  private JobLauncher launcher;

  @Autowired
  private Job job;

  @Scheduled(fixedRateString ="${frequence.move}")
  public void doTask() throws JobExecutionException {
      test();
      launcher.run(job, new JobParameters());
  }
}
```

In your `BatchConfigEMS` add the `@PropertySource` and make sure you have a `public static` bean of the type `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource( "resources.properties")
public class BatchConfigEMS {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {

        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a web application load the configuration ones and everything else should be auto wired. The placeholders should get replaced because of the added configurer.

Answer (score 0):

this is my file (resource.properties)

```
fournisseur.key =false
produit.key = true

frequence.move = 5000
frequence.delete = 5000
```

i want just take this key[frequence.move] from my file properties 
and use it here :

```
       @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${frequence.move}")
      public void doTask() {
 all the code here it work 
}
```

I write what you advice me and that doesn't work